# Find the shortest path in an graph containing at most two red edges

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, dijkstra

The question is :
[image]

I know that we should duplicate the graph into G1 and G2 and probably use Dijstra's algorithm. I am not sure how i should connect G1 and G2 in a way that i will get the right solution for this question.

Comment: Lets make it more interesting. Does the shortest path has to be simple path? meaning, is there a possibility that there might be a cycle? Well, the answer is no, because if we remove that cycle from the shortest path that has at most 2 red edges, we will get a new path that is shorter than our path. Thus, there can not be a cycle in the shortest path we found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost have the answer:

1. Make two more copies of the graph, so you have G, G1, and G2.
2. Remove the red edges from G2, change every red edge in G1 to point to the corresponding vertex in G2 instead of G1, and change every red edge in G to point to the corresponding vertex in G1.
3. Now, every path that has 2 red edges ends up in G2, and ALL paths that have 2 red edges end up in G2.  Similarly all paths that have 1 red edge end up in G1. Use Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest paths from s in G to all the vertexes in G, G1, and G2.
4. For each vertex in G, look at the paths to the corresponding vertices in G, G1 and G2, take the shortest one, and translate it back to the original graph. (because paths with less than 2 red edges are also acceptable)

Comment: You skipped a step. For every vertex v the solution is the minimum distance corresponding to the nodes in G, G1 and G2. This is because the condition is at most 2 red edges so you are allowed to get there with only one or none as well.

Comment: Thanks ! something that i dont understand, "change every red edge in G1 to point to the corresponding vertex in G2 instead of G1". What if a red edge points to another red edge ? then i can't have an edge from G1 to G2

Comment: Edges go to vertexes, not other edges.  If there was path A->B->C with 2 red edges, it now goes G.A->G1.B->G2.C.  The idea is that you can always  tell how many red edges you've traversed by whether you're in G, G1, or G2.

Comment: Thanks Matt! this is awesome explanation

Comment: Lets make it more interesting. Does the shortest path has to be simple path? meaning, is there a possibility that there might be a cycle? Well, the answer is no, because if we remove that cycle from the shortest path that has at most 2 red edges, we will get a new path that is shorter than our path. Thus, there can not be a cycle in the shortest path we found. @MattTimmermans